# WP_Query posts_per_page dont work with paged 1

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with WP_Query only on paged:1

`$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'paged' => 1));`

It return 181 results

But if i do this:

`$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'paged' => 2));`

It return 12 exact results.

181 its not my total posts

[image]

Maybe its a problem with sticky posts?

Answer (score 0):

Problem caused by sticky posts. Adding this parameters works fine:

```
$args['post__in']            = get_option('sticky_posts');
$args['ignore_sticky_posts'] = 1;
```